# how to dynamically generate barcode in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, barcode

I want to generate barcode `(code 39 or code 93 or code 128 or codabar)` that dynamically generate from number to number (ex: from number 001 to number 010 that have 10 barcode). Any ideas for this.

Comment: I have an excelent dll file that generates code 128 codebars as image it works but im learning asp/mvc and im not sure if you can add a dll file to your project

Comment: Im curious about this, and problably next month ill know this answer, but you can start here: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=barcode&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=4 or here: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=barcode

Answer (score 2):

The best advice anyone will give you about this in .NET is don't roll your own! Barcodes are finicky little bastards where the slightest offset on a glyph invalidates it.

Your best bet would be a commercial library for it such as the one by Apose. The reason I would suggest a commercial lib is because nearly every open-source lib I've seen for .NET were riddled with subtle errors that are a nightmare to debug...

If you absolutely must go with a free lib I would check out [Barcode Rendering Framework](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/)
as it's one of the least delicate open-source libs I've found.

Comment: thank you for suggest, but it not uses for web application

Comment: asp.net is for web applications. what are you planning on doing with it.

Comment: i had searched google and this forum and i think i use font format ([IDAutomationHC39M](http://www.dafont.com/idautomationhc39m.font)) or ([jQuery](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html)) is the best simple.

Answer (score -1):

It's is really hard if you do your own code, I recommend you to use a premade library, you can look for them in [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=barcode&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=%7C&ac=4) or [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=barcode), maybe just google a library you have to pay for or another option would be to use a jQuery plugin like this one ([jQuery BarCode](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html)).

Hope it helps